# Making a VB.net winform button look pressed from code behind

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I've got a basic VB.net 2.0 application together in VisualStudio 2005.

Within a form, I've tied [enter] in several text boxes to a button.  What I'd like to do is "press" the button from `getField_KeyDown()` to give the user a visual indication of what's happening.

With the code below, the button click work is done but the button's look doesn't change and the user is left without feedback.

```
Private Sub getField_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtGetKey.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        e.Handled = True
        Call btnGet.PerformClick()
    End If
End Sub
```

How can I make the button looked pressed while the `btnGet.PerformClick()` work is being done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set the `FlatStyle` of the button.  So your code will look like this:

```
Private Sub getField_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtGetKey.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        e.Handled = True
        btnGet.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
    End If
End Sub
```

This will change the button appearance - Don't forget to change it back to `FlatStyle.Standard`

Comment: I swear I tried that before posting the question and it wasn't working.  It does now, of course.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a checkbox and set the appearance to a button.

```
chkCheck.Appearance = Appearance.Button
```

You can also set this in the design mode.

And it behaves just the same as a normal checkbox. So you can assign a key pressed to the state of the checkbox.