# How to connect keyboard events to press down buttons in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a hangman game as a project in school, and we can't make the keyboard to function with the buttons that we have in our game. We have 29 buttons with letters "A-Å" and we can only press them using the mousepad/mouse. I'm programming this in VisualBasic.

Public Class Form1
    Private ord_liste() As String
    Private ord As String
    Private r As New Random
    Private feil As Single

```
Private Sub btn_click(ByVal btn As Button)
    btn.Enabled = False

    Call check(btn.Text)

End Sub

Private Sub Buttons_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click, Button4.Click, Button5.Click,
    Button6.Click, Button7.Click, Button8.Click, Button9.Click, Button10.Click, Button11.Click, Button12.Click, Button13.Click, Button14.Click, Button15.Click, Button16.Click,
    Button17.Click, Button18.Click, Button19.Click, Button20.Click, Button21.Click, Button22.Click, Button23.Click, Button24.Click, Button25.Click, Button26.Click,
    Button27.Click, Button28.Click, Button29.Click

    Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)

    Call btn_click(btn)
End Sub
```

'This is whats not working for me...

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    For Each btn As Button In Panel1.Controls.OfType(Of Button)()
        If e.KeyCode.ToString.ToLower = btn.Text.ToLower Then
            Call btn_click(btn)
        End If
    Next
End Sub



Private Sub check(ByVal letter As String)
    If ord.Contains(letter.ToLower) Then
        'Sjekke om bokstaven passer i ordet.
        Dim indexes As New List(Of Integer)
        For i As Integer = 0 To ord.Length - 1
            If ord.Substring(i, 1).ToLower = letter.ToLower Then
                indexes.Add(i)
            End If
        Next
        'Denne gjør at når du gjetter rett bokstav så blir den skrevet ut i tekstboksen.
        For Each Int As Integer In indexes
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Remove(Int * 4, 4).Insert(Int * 4, letter.ToUpper & "   ")
        Next
        'Du har vunnet
        If TextBox1.Text.Contains("_") = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Gratulerer, du har vunnet!", Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Call nyttspill()
        End If

    Else
        'Du gjettet feil bokstav.
        feil += 1

        Select Case feil
            Case 1
                Head.Visible = True
            Case 2
                Body.Visible = True
            Case 3
                Left_arm.Visible = True
            Case 4
                Right_arm.Visible = True
            Case 5
                Left_leg.Visible = True
            Case 6
                Right_leg.Visible = True
                MessageBox.Show("Beklager, men du har tapt. Ordet du skulle ha var: " & ord, Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                Call nyttspill()
        End Select
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub nyttspill()
    'Starter spillet på nytt og gjemmer kroppen.
    Head.Visible = False
    Body.Visible = False
    Left_arm.Visible = False
    Right_arm.Visible = False
    Left_leg.Visible = False
    Right_leg.Visible = False

    'Setter antall feil til 0.
    feil = 0

    'Velger nytt random ord.
    Dim i As Integer = r.Next(0, ord_liste.Count)
    ord = ord_liste(i)

    'Viser hvor langt det er.
    TextBox1.Clear()
    For int As Integer = 0 To ord.Length - 1
        TextBox1.Text &= "__  "
    Next

    'Knappene blir "utrykket" igjen.
    For Each btn As Button In Panel1.Controls.OfType(Of Button)()
        btn.Enabled = True
    Next

End Sub


Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim del() As String = {Environment.NewLine}
    ord_liste = My.Resources.ord_fil.Split(del, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

    Call nyttspill()
End Sub
```

End Class

This is the code we have so far.

Comment: I think you can proceed as in your example, just that you will need to pass a sender and the EventArgs as parameters

Comment: What does `btn_click()` do? Are you only concerned with the button's functionality, or do you actually want the button to look like it was clicked (visually) when you press a key?

Comment: I want it to be visually pressed and enter the key that I press into a Textbox.

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing the technique from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669156/making-a-vb-net-winform-button-look-pressed-from-code-behind), in your KeyDown handler you'll need to:

1. Identify which key/letter was pressed (a Case statement, perhaps)
2. Change the appropriate button's FlatStyle property,

   ```
   cmdAbutton.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
   ```
3. Call the event handler for the appropriate button, or perform the desired code,

   ```
   cmdAbutton.PerformClick()
   ```

Then, create a KeyUp handler very similar to your KeyDown where you,

1. Identify which key/letter was pressed, and
2. Revert the appropriate button's FlatStyle,

   ```
   cmdAbutton.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard
   ```